Ideal way to listen to SPL token transfer?
The solana cookbook subscribe to events snippet gives only sol balance at best,https://solana.com/developers/cookbook/development/subscribing-events.
So, i have used a signature using public key, and get transaction details and get the token transfer details calculated from pre and post token balances.Done in the below snippet. But i wonder if this the ideal way to do it? Is there a easier way to do this like in EVM with jut token address?
    async function logTokenAccountTransactions(account) {
  console.log("Account Object:", account); // account is the public key

  // Make sure to access the correct property
  const accountId = account || account.pubkey; // Adjust this line as needed

  if (!accountId) {
    console.error("Invalid account object or missing accountId/pubkey");
    return;
  }

  const signatures = await connection.getSignaturesForAddress(
    accountId,
    { limit: 1 }
  );// accountId is TO address

  console.log("==================> signature is ", signatures);

  for (const { signature } of signatures) {
    // let {signature }  = signatures
    const transaction = await connection.getTransaction(signature);

    if (transaction) {
      console.log(`*******Transaction postTokenBalances details: `, transaction.meta.postTokenBalances);
      console.log(`*******Transaction preTokenBalances details: `, transaction.meta.preTokenBalances);

      const instructions = transaction.transaction.message.instructions;
      const accountKeys = transaction.transaction.message.accountKeys
      const header = transaction.transaction.message.header
      console.log("Account ", accountKeys, header)
    } else {
      console.log(`Transaction ${signature} not found.`);
    }
  }

}


This looks correct to me! If you just care about transfers in and out of a particular account, you could also use accountSubscribe, but that will only give you the new state of the account.
More info at https://solana.com/docs/rpc/websocket/accountsubscribe
